# Python Tkinter, how to update table with live data?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to update my Tkinter table with live data. So Far I've managed to create the GUI and set values from the API in the table's labels. However I can't seem to update it once the window's main loop is running. Here is a sample of my code so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Label,Frame,Tk, Scale, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Entry
def getValue(value):
    print(value)

window = Tk()
window.title("Table GUI")
window.configure(bg="pink")
window.geometry("300x305")



varas1=StringVar()
varas2=StringVar()
varas3=StringVar()


vara1=StringVar()
vara2=StringVar()
vara3=StringVar()


varp1=StringVar()
varp2=StringVar()
varp3=StringVar()

varb1=StringVar()
varb2=StringVar()
varb3=StringVar()




frame2=Frame(window)
frame2.pack(fill="both")

tablayout=Notebook(frame2)

tab1=Frame(tablayout)

for row in range(11):
    for column in range (3):

    if row==0 and column==0:
        label= Label(tab1,text="Headline1", bg="green", fg="blue", padx=3, pady=3)
        label.config(font=('Arial',16))
        label.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        tab1.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

    if row==1 and column==2:
        label = Label(tab1,textvar=vara1,bg="pink", fg="Red", padx=3, pady=3) #Entry or Label with colours
        label.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        tab1.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

    if row==2 and column==2:
        label = Label(tab1,textvar=vara2,bg="pink", fg="Red", padx=3, pady=3) #Entry or Label with colours
        label.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        tab1.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

    if row==3 and column==2:
        label = Label(tab1,textvar=vara3,bg="pink", fg="Red", padx=3, pady=3) #Entry or Label with colours
        label.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        tab1.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

tablayout.pack(fill="both")
```

Then I put a function that queries a websocket in a while true loop

```
While true:
    Retrievedatafromwsusingaconnector()
    vara=apiresult['dataA']
    VarA[(vara[0]),
         (vara[1]),
         (vara[2])]
```

And finally, I link the variables received from the websocket to the ones I defined earlier on:

```
varas3.set(VarA[0]) 
varas2.set(VarA[1]) 
varas1.set(VarA[2])
```

Then run the window's mainloop:

```
window.mainloop()
```

I read in another similar post ([Python Tkinter, Display Live Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275043/python-tkinter-display-live-data)) that I could use the windows.update() function but I can't seem to see how I can run separately the ws queries from the windows.mainloop() while updating the table's labels at the same time. Perhaps I could do it in an asynchronous manner from the same code? Or do I have to create a database that get's updated and simply have the Tkinter read it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your script gets to mainloop() it stops there and won’t do anything else. There are a couple ways to get around this. The first option is instead of mainloop(), put your querie in a while True loop with window.update() at the end. This way you’ve built your own loop that updates Tkinter, like mainloop(), but that still allows you to run code inside the loop.
Second option would be to have a querie function that after some amount of time will call itself again, using a widget’s after method. You can read up on that here: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Comment: Great, the first option worked. Thank you very much

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to change the colour of one depending on the result the websocket returns? I tried to do some sort of conditional formatting using a variable change with the string var method then linking a colour to it and entering the colour variable in the bg: of the cell I wish to update whilst adding a condition to the cell I created:

Comment: You can change the color of labels and frames using widget.config(bg=color) where color is a string. You can use these preset color strings: http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Color_Charts_for_TKinter

Comment: You can also choose your own colors using hex color codes as strings: https://htmlcolorcodes.com/